Scraping site renders an empty CSV
This site (https://oig.hhs.gov/reports-and-publications/all-reports-and-publications/) lists out individual reports and I'm trying to scrape them using python/BS.
I'm trying to scrape the title, audit, agency, and date using the below code.
But it renders an empty CSV. Any suggestions on what I need to modify in the code?
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
 
url = "https://oig.hhs.gov/reports-and-publications/all-reports-and-publications/"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
 
reports = soup.find_all("div", class_="media")
 
report_data = []
 
for report in reports:
    title = report.find("h3").get_text(strip=True)
    audit = report.find("span", class_="audit").get_text(strip=True) if report.find("span", class_="audit") else "N/A"
    agency = report.find("span", class_="agency").get_text(strip=True) if report.find("span", class_="agency") else "N/A"
    date = report.find("span", class_="date").get_text(strip=True) if report.find("span", class_="date") else "N/A"
     
    report_data.append({
        "Title": title,
        "Audit": audit,
        "Agency": agency,
        "Date": date
    })
 
# Export to CSV
csv_file = "reports_data.csv"
with open(csv_file, mode='w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=["Title", "Audit", "Agency", "Date"])
    writer.writeheader()
    for data in report_data:
        writer.writerow(data)
 
print(f"Data exported to {csv_file}")


Is that url correct? Or how did you come of with those specific tags and classes?  Right now I'd say that none of those exists on the target page.

I don't know where you got your class names--are you are just guessing? When I view this page, there are no elements with class 'media', 'audit', 'date', etc. If you're not familiar with HTML, any element can have various attributes defined within it's opening tag. Attributes can have (pretty much) any value--there's no standard for class names or any other attribute. If you are attempting to locate elements based on their class attribute, you must find the exact class name in the HTML. You can use the Developer Console of any browser to accomplish this.
The following code locates report elements based on class name, then finds the details based on tag type:
reports = soup.find_all("div", class_="usa-card__container")

for report in reports:
   title = report.find("a").get_text(strip=True)
   audit, agency, date = [e.get_text(strip=True) for e in report.find_all("dd")]

